# Can't make simple tagless final example

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, tagless-final

I've read about tagless final and I think it's great. I wanted to build my own small example of this pattern and got the problem.

This is my code:

```
  trait Calculator[F[_]] {
    def sum(a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]]
    def minus(a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]]
  }

  object calculatorInstances {
    implicit val futureCalculator: Calculator[Future] = new Calculator[Future] {
      override def sum(a: Int, b: Int) =
        Future {
          Try(a + b).toEither
        }
      override def minus(a: Int, b: Int) =
        Future {
          Try(a - b).toEither
        }
    }
  }


  import calculatorInstances.futureCalculator
  def getPlusAndMinus[F[_]: Monad: Calculator](a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[String, Int]] = {
    for {
      sum <- Calculator[F].sum(a, b)
      res <- Calculator[F].minus(sum, b)
    } yield res
  }
```

This code doesn't work because of `not found: value Calculator` error. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add materializer:

```
object Calculator {
  def apply[F[_]: Calculator]: Calculator[F] = implicitly
}
```

It's better to put instances of type class `Calculator[F[_]]` (like implicit `futureCalculator`) to the same companion object `Calculator`, otherwise you'll have to `import calculatorInstances._`.

Don't forget to `import cats.syntax.flatMap._` and `import cats.syntax.functor._`.

`sum` in `sum <- Calculator[F].sum(a, b)` is of type `Either[Throwable,Int]` but `sum` in `Calculator[F].minus(sum, b)` is expected to be `Int`.

Maybe returning type of `getPlusAndMinus` should be `F[Either[Throwable, Int]]` instead of `F[Either[String, Int]]`.

Maybe the easiest way to fix `for` comprehension is to use monad transformer:

```
def getPlusAndMinus[F[_] : Monad: Calculator](a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]] = {
  (for {
    sum <- EitherT(Calculator[F].sum(a, b))
    res <- EitherT(Calculator[F].minus(sum, b))
  } yield res).value
}
```

Just in case, the whole code:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.Monad
//import cats.syntax.flatMap._ // not necessary if we use EitherT
//import cats.syntax.functor._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object App {

  trait Calculator[F[_]] {
    def sum(a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]]
    def minus(a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]]
  }

  object Calculator {
    def apply[F[_]: Calculator]: Calculator[F] = implicitly

    implicit val futureCalculator: Calculator[Future] = new Calculator[Future] {
      override def sum(a: Int, b: Int) =
        Future {
          Try(a + b).toEither
        }
      override def minus(a: Int, b: Int) =
        Future {
          Try(a - b).toEither
        }
    }
  }

  def getPlusAndMinus[F[_] : Monad: Calculator](a: Int, b: Int): F[Either[Throwable, Int]] = {
    (for {
      sum <- EitherT(Calculator[F].sum(a, b))
      res <- EitherT(Calculator[F].minus(sum, b))
    } yield res).value
  }
}
```